# Maintaining session with openfire using prebind_url in converse

Tags: javascript, session, xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I am using converse as a client with openfire and I want to maintain session with the openfire using web sockets and without specifying the user's password in the converse settings file. For this I wish to use prebind_url so that I can maintain session using sid, rid and jid. But as available in converse documentation for prebind_url

> This setting should be used in conjunction with authentication set to prebind and keepalive set to true.

and for keepalive it is mentioned that

> Currently the “keepalive” setting only works with BOSH and not with websockets. This is because XMPP over websocket does not use the same session token as with BOSH.

Can anyone please help with any way by which a session can be maintained using websockets without explicity password in converse settings